# Bad request using UrlFetchApp.fetch method

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to get the list of tags from Pinboard.in using it's api but I get an error when the fetch method is executed.

The code is:

```
function getTags(user, password) {
  var url ="https://"+user+":"+password+"@api.pinboard.in/v1/tags/get"
  var response=httpGet(url);
  return response;
}
function httpGet(theUrl)
    {
      var options = { "contentType" : "application/xml; charset=utf-8"} ;
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(theUrl,options);
      return response.getContentText();
    }
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error you get ? A better way is to check the value of response.getResponseCode() before returning response.getContentText()

Comment: I can't check the responseCode() because the program stops. The only thing I get is a message with this test: Bad request: https://user:password@api.pinboard.in/v1/tags/get (line 9) with a dismiss button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the user:password@ prefix notation is not supported by UrlFetchApp. Instead you'll have to construct the Authorization header manually, using code like:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.pinboard.in/v1/tags/get', {
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(user + ':' + password)
  }
});
```